# A transfer-matrix approach for multi-barriers

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to reproduce the results from  https://doi.org/10.1063/1.168430. The work study one-dimensional quantum system using a transfer-matrix formalism for multi-barriers with finite-step potentials.
I have used same  Mathematica-code given in paper's Appendices, but I can't plot the Figures and nothing happens.
The codes examples of the paper are shown below:

```
(*TEMPLATE FOR DISCOTINUITY AND PROPAGATION MATRICES*)
(*discontinuity matrix*)
d /: d[v1_, v2_] := 
 Block[{k1 = Sqrt[e - v1], k2 = Sqrt[e - v2]},
  da = (1 + k1/k2)/2;
  db = (1 - k1/k2)/2;
  Return[{{da, db}, {db, da}}]
  ]
(*propagation matrix*)
p /: p[v_, length_] := 
 Block[{kl = ro*length*Sqrt[e - v]},
  pa = E^(I*kl);
  pb = E^(-(I*kl));
  Return[{{pa, 0}, {0, pb}}]
  ]
(*GLOBAL VALUES SUPPORTING THE RECTANGULAR BARRIER MODEL*)
DIGITS = 10;
PRECISION = 40;
lastArg = 1;
band = 0;
period = 1;
delv = 0;
plotList = {};
ro = 10*Pi/9;
v1 = 0;
v2 = 1;
lengthBarrier = 1;
lengthGap = 1;
(*ROUTINES GENERATING TRANSFER MATRICES FOR RECTANGULAR BARRIER MODEL*)
makeTx /: makeTx[v1_, v2_, lengthBarrier_, lengthGap_] :=     
 Block[{tx, p1, p2, d1, d2, a, b, c},
  d1 = d[v1, v2];
  p1 = p[v2, lengthBarrier];
  d2 = d[v2, v1];
  p2 = p[v1, lengthGap];
  tx = N[p2.d2.p1.d1, PRECISION];
  Return[tx]
  ]
makeUnitCell /: makeUnitCell := Block[{tx, t, i},
  t = IdentityMatrix[2];
  For[i = 1, i <= period, i++,
   tx = makeTx[v1, v2, lengthBarrier, lengthGap];
   v2 = 2 + delv - v2;
   t = t.tx
   ];
  Return[t]
  ]
searchBand /: searchBand[start_, finish_, steps_] :=

 Block[{deleov, i, zeroTol, evals, eVals},
  PlotList = {};
  zeroTol = 1*10^(-DIGITS);
  e = start;
  deleov = (finish - start)/steps;
  eVals = Eigenvalues[makeUnitCell];
  lastArg = Arg[eVals[[1]]];
  For[i = 1, i <= steps + 1, i++,
   eVals = Eigenvalues[makeUnitCell];
   evals = Abs[eVals];
   If[Chop[Abs[evals[[1]]] - 1, zeroTol] == 0, saveArg[eVals[[1]]]];
   e = e + deleov
   ];
  band = 0;
  ]
saveArg /: saveArg[z_] := Block[{arg, negArg, kdoPi},
  arg = N[Arg[z], DIGITS + 1];
  If[arg >= 0, negArg = 0, negArg = 1];
  If[Sign[lastArg] + Sign[arg] == 0, band++];
  lastArg = arg;
  kdoPi = (arg + (negArg + band)*Pi)/(period*Pi);
  plotList = Append[plotList, N[{kdoPi, e}, DIGITS]];]
(*TRANSMISSION COEFFICIENT CALCULATION*)
tcoeff /: 
 tcoeff[start_, finish_, steps_, numberOfBarries_] :=

 Block[{deleov, i, t22, t},
  plotList = {};
  e = start;
  v1 = 0; v2 = 1; lengthGap = 1; lengthBarrier = 1;
  deleov = (finish - start)/steps;
  For[i = 1, i <= steps + 1, i++,
   t = makeUnitCell;
   t = MatrixPower[t, numberOfBarries];
   t22 = t[[2, 2]];
   plotList = Append[plotList, N[{e, (Abs[t22])^-2}, DIGITS]];
   ];
  ]
```

Comment: Oh my, the authors of the paper really did not know what they were doing: `For`- loops everywhere, `Return` and `TagSetDelayed` for no good reason... Please promise to me that you won't adapt their style of programming. But let's get to the real problem: The posted code constains only function definitions; these function are called nowhere. This is not a complete program that can be run and that produces anything.

Comment: Glimsing into the paper, I see that they spread function calls over their whole document. So I am afraid, you have to read it line by line in order to get to know how the defined functions are supposed to be used.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, Thanks for the attention! Actually, I'm using this paper as a toy-model for another more general problem that is getting the transmission for multiple rectangular barriers using a transfer-matrix. As an example, see <https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physb.2014.10.002>. With transfer matrix (eq. 1), I want to calculate the transmission probability (from eq. 5), Conductance (eq.6), and Fano factor (eq. 7).

Comment: Pretty ugly code indeed. Please note that some functions, such as the `tcoeff` function define  global (!) variables (`plotlist` in this case). My guess is that you are supposed to use these further on. This is, of course, a rather dangerous programming style. Note also that many function definitions without `Return` end in a semicolon `;` which means they don't return anything at all.

Comment: Looking better, there really are a lot of weird things in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is not surprising, but the code made in 1992 works. I just fixed a few typos and added a couple of blocks for convenience.

```
(*TEMPLATE FOR DISCOTINUITY AND PROPAGATION MATRICES*)(*discontinuity \
matrix*)d /: d[v1_, v2_] := 
 Block[{k1 = Sqrt[e - v1], k2 = Sqrt[e - v2]}, da = (1 + k1/k2)/2;
  db = (1 - k1/k2)/2;
  Return[{{da, db}, {db, da}}]]
(*propagation matrix*)
p /: p[v_, length_] := 
 Block[{kl = ro*length*Sqrt[e - v]}, pa = E^(I*kl);
  pb = E^(-(I*kl));
  Return[{{pa, 0}, {0, pb}}]]

(*ROUTINES GENERATING TRANSFER MATRICES FOR RECTANGULAR BARRIER MODEL*)
\

makeTx /: makeTx[v1_, v2_, lengthBarrier_, lengthGap_] := 
 Block[{tx, p1, p2, d1, d2, a, b, c}, d1 = d[v1, v2];
  p1 = p[v2, lengthBarrier];
  d2 = d[v2, v1];
  p2 = p[v1, lengthGap];
  tx = N[p2.d2.p1.d1, PRECISION];
  Return[tx]]
makeUnitCell /: makeUnitCell := 
 Block[{tx, t, i}, t = IdentityMatrix[2];
  For[i = 1, i <= period, i++, 
   tx = makeTx[v1, v2, lengthBarrier, lengthGap];
   v2 = 2 + delv - v2;
   t = t.tx];
  Return[t]]
searchBand /: searchBand[start_, finish_, steps_] := 
 Block[{deleov, i, zeroTol, evals, eVals}, plotList = {};
  zeroTol = 1*10^(-DIGITS);
  e = start;
  deleov = (finish - start)/steps;
  eVals = Eigenvalues[makeUnitCell];
  lastArg = Arg[eVals[[1]]];
  For[i = 1, i <= steps + 1, i++, eVals = Eigenvalues[makeUnitCell];
   evals = Abs[eVals];
   If[Chop[Abs[evals[[1]]] - 1, zeroTol] == 0, saveArg[eVals[[1]]]];
   e = e + deleov];
  band = 0;]
saveArg /: saveArg[z_] := 
 Block[{arg, negArg, kdoPi}, arg = N[Arg[z], DIGITS + 1];
  If[arg >= 0, negArg = 0, negArg = 1];
  If[Sign[lastArg] + Sign[arg] == 0, band++];
  lastArg = arg;
  kdoPi = (arg + (negArg + band)*Pi)/(period*Pi);
  plotList = Append[plotList, N[{kdoPi, e}, DIGITS]];]
(*TRANSMISSION COEFFICIENT CALCULATION*)
tcoeff /: tcoeff[start_, finish_, steps_, numberOfBarries_] := 
 Block[{deleov, i, t22, t}, plotList = {};
  e = start;
  v1 = 0; v2 = 1; lengthGap = 1; lengthBarrier = 1;
  deleov = (finish - start)/steps;
  For[i = 1, i <= steps + 1, i++, t = makeUnitCell;
   t = MatrixPower[t, numberOfBarries];
   t22 = t[[2, 2]];
   plotList = Append[plotList, N[{e, (Abs[t22])^-2}, DIGITS]]; 
   e = e + deleov]; plotList]
fig2[delv0_, st_, fin_, stp_] := 
 Block[{delv = delv0, DIGITS = 10, PRECISION = 40, lastArg = 1, 
   band = 0, period = 2, plotList = {}, ro = 10*Pi/9, v1 = 0, v2 = 1, 
   lengthBarrier = 1, lengthGap = 1}, searchBand[st, fin, stp]; 
  ListPlot[plotList, AxesLabel -> {"kd/\[Pi]", "E/V"}, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"delv = ", delv}]]]

 {fig2[0, .33, .35, 1000], fig2[0.25, .33, .35, 1000], 
  fig2[0.5, .35, .4, 1000]}

fig4[delv0_, st_, fin_, stp_, nob_] := 
 Block[{delv = delv0, DIGITS = 10, PRECISION = 40, lastArg = 1, 
   band = 0, period = 2, plotList = {}, ro = 10*Pi/9, v1 = 0, v2 = 1, 
   lengthBarrier = 1, lengthGap = 1}, tcoeff[st, fin, stp, nob]; 
  ListPlot[plotList, AxesLabel -> {"E/V", "T"}, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"Number of barriers = ", nob}], PlotRange -> All]]


fig4[0.5, .32, .33, 50000, 10]
```

[image: fig1]